GitHub Pages site not loading; consistently showing 404 message
I have only recently, probably 10 or so days ago, started using GitHub as a programmer and UX person, hence, I do not know the system inside and out. My first GitHub pages blog, which is currently in very early stages of development, went live some 4 days ago, and has been accessible in all of the browsers.
Since noon today, October 30th, 2024, I have been trying to launch another GitHub pages-based small utility, however, despite all of the successful commits and zero error messages, the page is not displaying in any of the browsers. It has been at least a few hours since the last successful commits of the mandatory index.html and Readme.md, but I have not been able to access the app’s main page on any of the browsers installed on my device. I have all of the mainstream browsers — Chrome, Brave, Safari, Opera, Firefox, and Tor — installed on my device, but whenever I try to access the page app, regardless of the browser used, I still get Page Not Found (404) error message.
The url of the still under development app is: Text Processor: Markup Your Text Expeditiously.
You can access my main GitHub page/account at the following URL: Irfan Surdar On GitHub: Rigorous Mind
If an expert in GitHub pages related troubleshooting can help me pinpoint the problem as to why the page failing to load, then I would greatly appreciate any assistance in this matter.
As a novice user of the GitHub system, I have read all of the relevant pages and documents available on the GitHub’s server, however, I have not been able to find the reason for the GitHub page’s based site’s failure to load.
